# Start monit as a foreground process in docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, monit

I want to start monit process in docker.

Since its getting daemonized, the container is getting completed once monit starts. What is the best way to run it as a foreground process?

Comment: what do you meant by: "the container is getting completed once monit starts"?

Comment: In order for a docker to run, there should be one process always running in foreground. Once that process is completed, the container will be stopped. Here monit starts as a daemon process,so there is no foreground process and the container is getting stopped.

Comment: Please share you monit file along with your docker run command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Monit:

```
Running monit in the foreground
To run monit in the foreground and provide feedback on everything it is detecting, use the -Ivv option:

root #monit -Ivv
```